# How to handle exception the right way in c# console app

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, exception

I have a small console app which will be scheduled on different intervals of the day, this console app will download files from ftp.
I have a class called BatchProcessor, which is downloading the files from the ftp, unzipping them based on the vendor type putting them into the different vendors folder and later reading and storing into SQL Server database.

I need some advice that what I am doing is right or wrong because I need to catch exception almost at any stage....

**Here is the code skeleton**.
**Program.cs**

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
var batchProcessor = new BatchProcessor();
            batchProcessor.Start();
        }
    }
```

**This is the BatchProcessor class**

```
public class BatchProcessor
{
    public bool Start()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = Connect();
            if (!result) return false;

            result = SearchLatestFiles();
            if (!result) return false;

            result = DownloadFiles();
            if (!result) return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

    public bool Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            // 1. Connect to FTP
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }

    public bool SearchLatestFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            // 1. Look for the latest fils
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

    public bool DownloadFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            // 1. Latest files found so download them.
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the application will be running unattended, your best way to diagnose errors is to deploy some kind of logging. I would recommend to use log4net available as a Nuget package. It is easy to install and configure and before throwing an error you should log error message and stack. 
Good practice to review these logs daily.
One more thing: You are throwing cough errors in your class, but main  does not handle these errors - it will lead to app crash and abnormal termination.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks Yuri, I was thinking the same way but was unable to make a decision, now I will follow your recommendation.